# Dynamically handling data columns in csv for import to Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, python-3.x

I'm new to python (3) and having a hard time with finding relevant examples for how to handle the following scenario. I know this is on the verge of being a "what's best" question, but hopefully there is a clearly appropriate methodology for this.

I have csv data files that contain timestamps and then at least one column of data with a name defined by a master list (i.e. all possible column headers are known). For example:

File1.csv

```
date-time, data a, data b
2014-01-01, 23, 22
2014-01-01, 23, 22d
```

File2.csv

```
date-time, data d, data a
2014-01-01, 99, 20
2014-01-01, 100, 22
```

I've been going in circles trying to understand when to use tuples, lists, and dictionaries for this type of scenario for import into postgresql. Since the column order can change and the list of columns is different each time (although always from a master set), I'm not sure on how to best generate a data set that includes the time stamp and columns and then perform an insert into a postgresql table where unspecified columns are provided a  value.

Given the dynamic nature of the columns' presence and the need to maintain the relationship with the timestamp for the Postgresql import via psycopg, what is recommended? Lists, lists of lists, dictionaries, or tuples?

I'm not begging for specific code, just some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Is the insertion going into one postgresql table, with all unspecified columns being null, or are they going into different tables?

Comment: One table with unspecified columns being null. Thanks for seeking clarification.

Comment: Look into the `csv` module, it'll save you much pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `csv` module to parse input file and by it's first row you can build (prepare) `psycopg` insert statement with column names and `%s` instead of values. For rest of rows simply execute this statement with row as values:

```
connect_string = 'dbname=test host=localhost port=5493 user=postgres password=postgres'
connection = psycopg2.connect(connect_string)
cursor = connection.cursor()
f = open(fn, 'rt')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    cols = []
    for row in reader:
        if not cols:
            cols = row
            psycopg_marks  = ','.join(['%s' for s in cols])
            insert_statement = "INSERT INTO xyz (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (','.join(cols), psycopg_marks)
            print(insert_statement)
        else:
            print(row)
            cursor.execute(insert_statement, row)
finally:
    f.close()

...
```

For your example you will have to correct column names.